# Derive expression for heat flow from oil bath to metal sphere

Tags: physical-chemistry, heat, thermal-conductivity

> A spherical ball of iron is put into a hot bath of oil. The iron ball is initially at a low temperature and heat transfer from the oil to the iron will increase the temperature of the iron ball.
>
> Use the concept of heat transfer coefficients to express the heat flow (i.e. the quantity with units J/s) from the oil to the ball. Denote your variables according to the notation in **Table 1**. Notice that not all variables in Tab. 1 might show up in your expression. Variables not listed in **Table 1** must not be used in your final expression.
>
> **Table 1**: Notations
> $$
> \begin{array}{ll}
> \hline
> c_{p, f} & \text{ heat capacity oil} \\
> c_{p, s} & \text{heat capacity iron} \\
> D & \text{diameter iron ball} \\
> h & \text{heat transfer coefﬁcient} \\
> k_f & \text{thermal conductivity oil} \\
> k_s & \text{thermal conductivity iron} \\
> Q & \text{heat ﬂow oil to iron (J/s)} \\
> R & \text{radius of the iron ball} \\
> T_s & \text{temperature iron ball} \\
>   & \text{(can be assumed homogeneous)} \\
> T_0 & \text{bulk temperature oil} \\
> ρ_s & \text{density iron} \\
> ρ_f & \text{density oil} \\
> \hline
> \end{array}
> $$

I'm really unsure of how to solve this problem. I know that the heat flow for a sphere with an inner and outer radius is

$$Q = \frac{4πkR_o}{1 - R_o/R_a}(T_0 - T_a),$$

but here I only have the radius of the whole sphere. So, how do I write the expression for the heat flow then?

Comment: If you let the outer radius approach infinity, you will be able to estimate the heat flow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Newton's law of cooling is

$$q = A h (T_0 - T_S )$$

With the area of the sphere being

$$A = 4 \pi R^2$$